# How do I handle multiple successful status codes with ant missing-link?

Tags: ant

I am using the [missing-link](https://code.google.com/p/missing-link/) http task to push build artifacts to our artifact depository.  The problem is that if I push a new artifact, I get an HTTP response code of 201.  If I push over an existing artifact, I get a 204.  Both of these are valid in my context.  But the `expected` attribute of `<http>` only accepts a single response code.  I tried `expected="201,204"` and `expected="201 204"` but I get a `NumberFormatException` when executing that ant node.  Is there a way to allow both 201 and 204 but treat any other responses as a failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Not directly as you tried.  You'd have to modify and rebuild it.  I checked the code, `expected` is an `int`. as you found it won't take a list.

It would be an ugly workaround but you could set `failonunexpected=false`.

you could make it less ugly if you continued no matter what the http return was by setting `failonunexpected=false` and then put the status in a property `statusProperty="http.status"` which you could use to  fail the build if `http.status` wasn't either `201 or 204`.  something like:

```
<condition property="http.status.ok">
  <matches pattern="20[14]" string="${http.status}"/>
</condition>
<fail message="Bad http status ${http.status}" unless="http.status.ok"/>
```

Tell me more about your artifact repository. is it maven or ivy layout? you may be able to leverage [Ivy's publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/publish.html) task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't know too much about the repo as it was set up by another developer on the team and I think it was custom-built, not something from open source.  I think I will just exec curl and punt on the missing link stuff.  That should give me good compatibility and error detection.

Comment: I think you may have better luck with the http taks than with execing to curl.  I admit I typed the snippet above from memory yesterday, but I tested it just now and it works.  You'll get better logging and better failure messages to the user.